# How to use relative names in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Many "advanced" (aka: VBA) excel tutorials on the web or even excel's vba help encurage us to use the

```
Range("B2:B10")
```

method (to be precise: object) for selecting cells or getting values. In the same place they often add it's totally ok to use predefined names as well:

```
Range("valuesabove")
```

On the other hand I fell in love with the incredible power of relatively defined cell names. They make it so much easier to write and handle big composite formulas, and basically to refer to nearly anything.

However, **relative names don't work in the *Range("valuesabove")* method the way we are used to it.**

Usually (when used on the worksheet) relative names are relative to the currently selected cell or to the cell in which they are used.

In VBA's Range() object this is not true. *Range* is relative to a WorkSheet object, by default to the ActiveSheet. But ActiveSheet is represenetd by its leftupper cell, A1. And this is what Range turns out to be relative to. And this is why absolute names *($C$23)* do work with it, and relative ones *("one column to the left, two rows up")* don't.

So my question is:
How can I harness the power of relative names in VBA then?

---

### EDIT:

Realising that my question was rather unclear (thx's go to you guys commenting tirelessly) let me try to put it in a specific form and clarify terms:

IMHO on an excel worksheet it is *very comfortable* to use names in order to refer to cells or define calculated values by functions based on cell values.

[In excel **a reference to a cell can be either relative, absolute, or mixed**.](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Next-50598462-63f0-476d-a523-f664c64d5dbb) This is true also when creating names. Thus we can speak about absolute, relative or mixed names (in terms of referring of course).

Here an **absolute name** is used a couple times (created using excel's Trace Dependents function):
[image: absolute name]

Name "name" = `$D$2`

A **relative name** is used a couple times here:
[image]

Name "upright24" *while, e.g. cell A7 is selected* = `C3` (without $ signs!). But this changes constantly according to the selected cell or region. You can check it in the name manager! (Ctrl+F3)

And this is what we can consider as a **mixed name**:
[image: mixed name]

Name "rel_serialnumber" *while, e.g. cell C6 is selected* = `$B6`. The row of which (*6*) changes constantly according to the selected cell or region.

The creation of a relative or a mixed name is explicitly based on the active cell at the moment of creating the name. The creation of an absolute name naturally doesn't rely on the cursor position.

Note, that

- absolute names mean a dinamic offset from the referenced cell, which is one and only
- relative names mean a static offset from the referenced cell, which thus changes always corresponding to the place where the name is used
- mixed names mean a mixed (or half-dynamic) offset from the referenced cell, the row or column of which thus changes always corresponding to the place where the name is used while the other remains always the same (the offset in one or the other direction remains zero).

---

Okay, now here is the thing. I have a database-like excel sheet where I handle the rows like records and the columns as fields for properties. The user uses this thing as follows: he "selects a record" by placing the cursor in any cell of the row of the desired record. Then he presses a big [command button](http://cdn.extendoffice.com/images/stories/doc-excel/change-button-color/doc-change-button-color1.png) which starts my VBA macro. This intends to open a prepared skeleton file and fill some specific cells in it (which are btw defined by absolute names) with some values (which are defined by mixed names) from the selected record.

Since `Range("name")` is considered ok to use in VBA (see above) I thought `Range("relativename")` or `Range("mixedname")` will work just as fine while automatically relying on the active cell.
**I couldn't be worse.**
**Only `Range("absolutename")` works in the way one would expect! Explanation see above.**

So I'm after a function / method / object that is possibly as comfortable to use with a `"relativename"` or a `"mixedname"` as `Range("absolutename")` is.

Comment: its not clear what your asking,  in vba   you can write   dim valuesabove as Range   , then  valuesabove = range("B2:B10") , now you can use  valuesabove as that range

Comment: Are you talking about r1c1 notation?  ...In which, if I want set `D4 = C3*10`, I could use something like: `Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "R[-1]C[-1]*10"`??  Can you give an example of a line of VBA code that doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: In r1c1 notation I still have the struggle to find out what offset I currently need. I would want to get rid of that by using relative names in VBA too. For example I want the "rel_serialnumber" name to represent the B cell of the current row because every row is a record and column B contains the serial numbers. And my vba code will run based on the record (row) of the selected cell.

Comment: So if cells `a1 b1 C1`  are `Dogs Cats TotalAnimals`, and I select A1:C10 and `create names from selection`-->`Names from Top Row`, then I can put `=Dogs+Cats` in C2:C10 and Excel will know to add A and B from the proper row. _(c4 = a4+b4, etc)_  Is that the behavior you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what a relative name is :)
Note, however, that a static name always means a _dynamic offset_ depending on the currently selected cell (eg. "how many rows/cols between the current one and the referred one"). A relative name means a static offset (at least partially) ("three columns to the left, one row upwards" or "three columns to the left, how many rows to the referred row").

Comment: So going back to my previous example, how does the result of `Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Dogs+Cats"` compare with the behavior you want?  How about `Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"`

Comment: I don't want to set any cell's formula. I want to get the value of cell B of the row of the currently selected cell by saying something like Range("B_cell_in_current_row").

Comment: How can you use a relative reference in VBA without telling VBA what it is relative to? What happens if you specify the active cell?

Comment: Good question. There is always an active cell. And I especially want to use the active cell (well, the row of it) that the user selected before running my macro. I am looking for a method that works based on a given name and the ActiveCell.

Comment: What happens if you try `ActiveCell.Range("valuesabove")`?

Comment: So you're after a more compact version of `my_Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("Dogs").Column).Value`?

Comment: Adam: yes! It is just that 'Range("name")' doesn't work in the way we would expect when the name's reference is relative. But yes, this describes what I would like.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are looking for `Range.Offset()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx

However you could do it as:

```
'Your example Range(Col_B_in_current_row) as
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select

'Your example Range("B2:B10") -> Range("valuesabove") as
Range("B2:B10").Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

Just seems like a relatively simple syntax already exists for this.

Comment: No, sorry, at Range.Offset() I still would need to calculate the offset values for reaching the desired cell.
By using relative names I want to be able to say something like Range("B_cell_in_the_current_row").

Comment: What about `Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select` to get to where you need to go?

Comment: OP doesn't want to use either "B" or a numerical offset - he wants to use the _name_ of the column:  `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("Dogs").Column)`

Comment: Using the "name" of the column is completely different then using a relative reference.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Yep.  I wouldn't call it a "relative reference" either - but after a ridiculously long back and forth with him, I am pretty sure that is what he wants. _"I want the "rel_serialnumber" name to represent the B cell of the current row because every row is a record and column B contains the serial numbers. And my vba code will run based on the record (row) of the selected cell"_

Comment: @Adam So why can't he just say "B"?  If it is always B then my code `Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select` is the simplest option available.

Comment: The code is much more comprehensible if I can use `"rel_serialnumber"` rather than just `B`.
Additionally, if someone moves a complete column, the names change correspondingly while the VBA code dont.

Comment: @Greenberet - I would recommend a major edit of your question to make it more clear what you are after.  You are using _"relative"_ in a way that is unfamiliar to many people, which is why everyone keeps recommending non-solutions.  Show an example, with named columns, and specify what syntax you would like to be able to use.  It is an interesting question, but I don't know if someone out there who knows the answer would recognize it (assuming a satisfactory answer exists - I don't know)

Comment: @Adam - You're right. I've done quite some additional work on the Q, so there you have it. I hope it's a lot more understandable now. THX for the encouraging words.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a proper and compact solution. It's

```
Names("mixedname").RefersToRange
```

Not as short as `Range("mixedname")` would be but it is really providing the expected values.

**UPDATE:**

This solution is mostly unuseful if you want to copy relative-named cell values in a source workbook to relative-named cells in a dest workbook with a single codeline. This is because `Names()` relies on the *actual* position of the cursor which is depending on which workbook is currently the active one and in most cases this won't be ok for the other.

In this case the non-fixed part of the name has to be stored:

`sourcerow = ActiveCell.Row
[...]
'opening a wbk, this also makes it the active one
[...]
Names("dest").RefersToRange = mysheet.Cells(sourcerow, mybook.Names("src").RefersToRange.Column)`

Answer (score 0):

To reference a Range relative to another Range you can use this syntax:

`myRange.Range("namedRange")`

> Note: This *only* works if both the Row offset AND the Column offsets are positive. For example if the "Refers to" formula for the named range is "=Offset(A1,*r*,*c*)", then the above syntax will throw an error if *Either* *r* *Or* *c* is negative. But, it will work if both are positive.
>
> The asymmetry is unfortunate but business as usual for VBA...

To Reference the third column in the row of the current ActiveCell:

`ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("C1")`

To reference a cell offset by (for example) 1 row and 3 columns relative to the `ActiveCell`:

`ActiveCell.Range("C2")`

Obviously, you can use the same syntax with the `Selection` Object or any other Range value in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
 If Not Intersect(Target.Address,ThisWorkbook.Sheets('sheetname).Range('RangeName)) Is Nothing Then _
 'Do whatever you want down here. 
 ThisWorbook.Sheets('sheetname).Range('RangeName).Offset(0,Target.Row) 
  End If 
  End Sub`

This should send you on the right path to what you want (which is super unclear). Use the worksheet change event to bring in user worksheet selections and changes into VBA modules. Put it into the relevant sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I did get it to work - sort of. I don't know what is different about the simple example below, but it works. At first I thought selection mattered, but no - it works without changing the active cell.

(I still can't get it to work in my main spreadsheet.)

- Named range: "TestName" = Sheet1!$H1
- Values in H1:H10  = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

  ```
  Sub Test()
  Dim x As Integer
      For x = 0 To 10
          Range("A1").Offset(x, 0).Value = Range("A1").Offset(x, 0).Range("Testname").Value
      Next x
  End Sub
  ```

  Result: A1:A10 =  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10